# PhoneGap user defined native event

Tags: javascript, events, cordova

PhoneGap has pre-defined event (deviceready, pause, resume, online, etc), and developer can add listener on it.

is it possible to define my own event and fire from the *native* thread, then the js callback can be invoked?

or is there any other way to asynchronously triger javascript functions?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a link between native code and your JavaScript in the webview with plugins. Check out the docs: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: thanks,
on my understanding, the PhoneGap plugins are always from js to native, and back to js when the natvie functions finished.
what i want is the oppsite way: from native to js

Comment: I believe you can pass a callback from JS to native as soon as your app loads and then invoke it in the native language whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways for solve your question;
If you want define your functions to your application, you can download the phonegap source file. You can define your functions with phonegap source. You can look these links; http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COoXbFegiWw
or you can write plugin for your application.

I hope that helps...